# c-make String in Reverse with helper swap function use only pointers

Tags: c

I need write the following function: char * Rev(char * str, int size);

The function get *pointer to string. It should replace the order of words within str, and return the result in the pointer. Only need reverse order for the words. Must use the helper swap function. In this function, there is no use of [] anywhere, ONLY USE pointers. Printing via main only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
char *str1,*str2,*pRev;
char *pstr="YPEFMI ICMKMS JGLYZJ";

 swap(&str1, &str2); 
 getchar(); 

*pRev =*RevWords (pstr,SIZE)

return 0;
}

methods.c

void swap(char* str1, char* str2);
char * Rev(char * string, int size);

//The function replaces the contents of both strings 1s and 2s.
void swap(char* str1, char* str2)
{
    // if both of them are zero characters then stop
    if (*str1 == '\0' && *str2 == '\0')
        return;
    // else swap the contents of the pointers
    else
    {
        char tmp = *str1;
        *str1 = *str2;
        *str2 = tmp;
        // advance both pointer and swap them too if thye are not '\0'
        swap(++str1, ++str2);        
    }
}
char * Rev(char * string, int size)
{ //no idea-->NOT work in reverse.
char string[SIZE * (SIZE + 1)]
char *str = (char *)(malloc (SIZE * SIZE + SIZE-1));  
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        memcpy(string + i * SIZE, matrix + i, SIZE);
        if (i < SIZE - 1) {
         swap(*(string + i * SIZE + SIZE));
        } else {
          swap(*(string + i * SIZE + SIZE)) = 0;
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

The swap method work but REV method NOT work.

For example:

pStr = YPEFMI ICMKMS JGLYZJ

pRev = -->JGLYZJ ICMKMS YPEFMI <--

Comment: Quite often, writing `char *pstr="YPEFMI ICMKMS JGLYZJ";` means that the compiler will store the string in read-only memory, which in turn means you can't change the string — and your program may well crash.  Use `char pstr[] = "YPEFMI ICMKMS JGLYZJ";` to give you a modifiable array.  I've not checked whether that's the only problem; it is likely there are others too..

Comment: Indeed, in `main()`, there's a problem with `swap(&str1, &str2);` — you're calling the function with the addresses of two uninitialized pointers.  That's unlikely to lead to happiness.  There's another major problem there; you pass two `char **` values, but the function expects two `char *` values.  You need to ensure you put prototypes in a header and include the header in both source files to allow the compiler to cross-check that you're using the functions correctly.  You need to add more options to your compiler so it complains about undeclared functions, etc.  Or get a better compiler!